# Trying to debug sluggish VS Code performance

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I have found that VS Code is working more slowly than usual this past month, at least when dealing with Jupyter notebooks. Code that runs well in JupyterLab is taking much longer to execute within VS Code. I've noticed some other performance issues as well:

1. VS Code will sometimes take a second or more on occasion to execute each cell, even if it's something that should take just milliseconds or less (e.g. displaying a value already in RAM). This considerably slows down runtimes within notebooks that have hundreds of cells.
2. VS Code sometimes frezees up at the start of a program, producing one or more 'The window is not responding' messages.
3. There will sometimes be a significant lag between executing a cell and seeing the output of the cell. Closing and reopening the notebook sometimes helps.
4. VS Code sometimes just freeze in the process of executing code, forcing me to restart it.
5. The program may also lag when I'm entering text into a markdown window; it may take several seconds to see what I typed.

Here's some information about my setup. I'm happy to share additional specs that might be helpful in solving this issue.

Laptop: Gigabyte Aorus 15P YD with 64 GB of RAM, 11th-Gen i7-11800H processor, 1TB hard drive, and Nvidia RTX 3080 Mobile GPU

Ubuntu version: 22.04.4 LTS
VS Code version: 1.86.2 (I uninstalled and reinstalled it today)
Extensions include:

1. Jupyter (v2024.1.1)
2. Python (v2024.2.0)

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use Jupyter's default web UI? I think VSCode is starting and connecting to a background Jupyter server over a localhost network connecting, so any changes to your network settings could have confused VSCode